# How to add a path to webpack config?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I created a simple project with vue-cli: `vue init webpack myProject`
It created a set of files and folders in `myProject` folder, then I run the project with `npm run dev`

My question is, I want to add to my `src/components` folder. Here's my file structure:

```
+ src
     + components
         + component1
            + index.js
            + component1.vue
```

index.js:

```
export { default } from './component1.vue';
```

component1.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
    span this is my component
</template>
```

I find the `build/webpack.base.conf.js` file and add this line:

```
resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
   alias: {
     vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
     '@': resolve('src'),
     components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
  },
},
```

Then I add this to my App.vue

```
<script>

import Component1 from 'components/component';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
     'component1': Component1,
   },
};
</script>
```

Which resulted in error message: `This dependency was not found`
How do I add the components folder to my webpack configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should do:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'components': resolve('src/components'),
      'core': resolve('src/components/core'),
      'common': resolve('src/components/common'),
      'mixin': resolve('src/components/common/mixin'),
      'private': resolve('src/components/private'),
      'public': resolve('src/components/public'),
      'services': resolve('src/services')
    }
  }
```

Make sure your root folder is named **src**.

Then you can access directly from everywhere, for example:

```
import FormMixin from 'mixin/FormMixin'
```

Answer (score 1):

in file `webpack.base.conf.js` change
`components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components')` to `components: resolve('src/components/component1')`
and file `App.vue` change `import Component1 from 'components/component'` to `import Component1 from 'components/component1'`